# Can't ping server that resolves using avahi-resolve

Tags: avahi, nsswitch, mdns

I have a server I've discovered from a Manjaro client using avahi named `unaha-closp`.  However, when I ping it I get:

```
ping: unaha-closp.local: Name or service not known
```

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` my hosts line is:

```
hosts: mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `strace getent hosts unaha-closp.local` on a machine which worked and the machine that didn't, it turns out the machine that didn't work never accessed avahi at all.  I was missing the `nss-mdns` plugin, which I got using:

```
sudo pamac install --no-upgrade nss-mdns
```